# Live Input does not change text on val update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an cloned input field that is calculated, then formatted using the following:

```
$("#LTV_CFS").val(updatedLTV.toFixed(2) + "%");
```

Through `console.log()`, I can see that the calculated value is, for example, `33.33%`. I read around and learned that I won't be able to see the value in live view but I'm not seeing the text in the input field update when the value is set. What I *am* seeing in the input text is 33.33333333333 repeating.

```
<input id="LTV_CFS" name="LTV" type="text" placeholder="0.00%" class="form-control default-input" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
```

No matter what I've done, the value does not want to change to what I set it and it just stays the unformatted decimal.

I've tried the following: `.attr("value", updatedLTV.toFixed(2) + "%")`, `.attr("text", updatedLTV.toFixed(2) + "%")`, `.prop("value", updatedLTV.toFixed(2) + "%")`.

Then I have the same calculation and formatting occur on a change event and it works perfectly as intended. I would believe that it's a load issue but everything is under a `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You will want to create a jsfiddle or use SO's snippet creator to post your working code. Otherwise no one will be able to provide any response that will help.

Comment: I just tested it and it works perfectly to me, do you have any trigger function attached to `onchange` event? Try setting up a jsFiddle or test the code with the snippet provided for your question while editing and check the results..